# jquery/javascript conflict error, trouble with jquery old version

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, select, radio-button

I need to hide an element when radio button changes, right now its working fine with ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js version, but many other things like slider, checkout, shipping method are disturbed when I include this jquery in my opencart website.
any suggestion of how I can do that with simple javascript or any other method?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $('input:radio[name=custom_field[6]]').change(function() {
            if (this.value == '2') {
                $('input:radio[name=payment_method][value=cod]').show();
                $('div.checkout-payment-methods div.radio:nth-child(5)').show();
                 }
                else if (this.value == '1') {
                $('input:radio[name=payment_method][value=cod]').hide();
                $('div.checkout-payment-methods div.radio:nth-child(5)').hide();
                }
            });
         });
    </script>

<div id="input-payment-custom-field6">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="custom_field[6]" value="2">
            Evidence
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="custom_field[6]" value="1">
            Invoice (Can not issue invoice with cash on delivery)
        </label>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="checkout-content checkout-payment-methods">
    <h2 class="secondary-title">Means of payment</h2>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="hellaspay" checked="checked">
            Debit / Credit card
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="bank_transfer">
            Bank deposit                           
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="pp_standard">
            PayPal                            
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="cod">
            Pay on delivery                            
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="pay_at_store">
            Payment at Stark                           
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use ```$('input:radio[name="custom_field[6]"]').click(function(){
       if( $(this).is("checked") ) {
            // Do something
       } else {
           // Do something
      }
})```

Comment: is there any way to achieve the current result without using jquery?

Comment: Could you please share u code html section

Comment: HTML section added, when invoice is selected in first radio group i want to hide payment on delivery in second radio group.
Note* HTML is not editable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use vanilla js

```
document.querySelector('input[name$="custom_field[6]"]').addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (this.value === '2') {

    }
    else if (this.value === '1') {

    }
});
```